# StoreKit delegate functions are not getting called

Tags: iphone, storekit

I wanted help from you guys. I have implemented the storekit code in my iPhone/iPad app and I am testing the application on iPad 1 with iOS 3.2.

I tried to test the application after performing all the steps like adding the products in for an application in iTunes connect and using provisioning profile to run that app on my iPad but when i run the application Storekit delegate functions are never called neither it gives any error and it never crashes. I can't figure out what is the problem.

Please help me to resolve this.

Below is the code which i have used

```
- (void) requestProductData
{

    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
    initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject:@"myproductid"]];


    request.delegate = self;           
    [request start];
}
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    // populate UI
    [request autorelease];
}

- (void) request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",errorMessage);
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"inside request finish");
}
```

I call the requestProductData but none of the delegate function is called.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: have u upload ur app in itunes and reject instantly ?

Comment: no I have not uploaded app on iTunes. The status is ready to upload binary in iTunes

Comment: i think u have to upload it and after sometime u have to reject it before it goes for review process.

Comment: Hello PJR I have uploaded the app and rejected the binary and still it is the same problem the delegates are not still getting called. I am using Xcode 4. Can you please help me out?

Comment: I'm having this, but instead of simply not working it's actually crashing the app...

Answer (score 1):

I figure this is a bit late and you would of solved it by now, but I am trying to resolve another issue, came across your question and was wondering if you had the delegates in your interface file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@end
```

I suspect you did have the above code and as said solve it, but just in case someone else has the same issue and has forgotten to include the delegates in the h file.

Comment: Thanks! it fixed my problem!! (my class implemented only SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol which I thought is good enough)